# Displaying errors on frontend user forms

Tags: craft3, users

I'm trying to get some feedback for the user on registration when the username already exists but I don't know in which object the errors are.

I use the form they provide in the docs:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/user-registration-form.html

Same for the forgot password form if the user doesn't exists in the system, I'm not able the provide the right feedback with this form:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/forgot-password-form.html

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with the user registration for in your link and got the expected behavior when you try to register with a username that already exists.

[image]

A few things to check.

1. Make sure you have public registration enabled in the Control Panel under Settings->Users->Settings.
2. When you're testing registering a user in your front-end form, make sure you're logged out of your current user account.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work on a module route, it seems to work fine on my homepage.  
I'm able to access the error with:
    {% if craft.app.session.has('error') %}
        <ul class="form__errors-list spacer spacer--xsm">
            <li>{{ craft.app.session.get('error') }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
But then I don't have the loginName, rememberMe and errorCode. Any idea what I need to do to just use the docs example and make the magic work?